# I can't get Apple Push Notifications to work with TestFlight using External Testing

Tags: ios, apple-push-notifications, testflight

I am developing an App that uses apple push notifications. Push notifications work without problem with the development release of the app. But as soon as I get it to TestFlight for external testing I get the following error on the server trying to send the push notification:

```
Notification caused error: 8 for device
```

I cleared all device registration Tokens before uploading the app so I am sure the tokens are being registered with the TestFlight version of the app.

I have, of course gotten a Production certificate for Apple Push Services, so when I manually test the APN connection using:

```
openssl s_client -connect gateway.push.apple.com:2195 -cert apn-push-cert.pem -key apn-push-key.pem  -CAfile entrust_2048_ca.cer # production
```

I get: `Verify return code: 0 (ok)` So this part should be OK

When I check the App ID on the member center it states that the Push Notification is Enabled for Distribution.

And when I view the summary of the App Archive that I uploaded to TestFlight, it is signed with a Distribution profile and I can see that it has 6 Entitlements among which it states: **aps-environment production**.

So what I am missing? Any help would be very much appreciated.

Comment: Thanks, but as I mentioned above the aps-environment is already production. I am starting to think has more to do with the server sending the notifications. I am using the apn module for node.